# SugarCRM: Get lead for quote custom pdf template

Tags: php, templates, pdf, sugarcrm

I want to create a custom pdf template for quotes in SugarCRM 7.
The template with footer, logo etc. is working, but I cannot output the adress, name etc. of the lead which is in relationship with the quote.

I can choose a lead in edit view and the quote is associated to the lead correctly.

So, how can I print out the lead informations in the quote?

My try:

```
 require_once('modules/Leads/Lead.php');
        $contact = new Lead();
        $contact->retrieve($this->bean->leadsid_c);

   $lead = new Lead();
$lead->retrieve($bean->leads_quotes_1_c.contacts_leads_1contacts_ida );

 $addressBS[0][$mod_strings['LBL_PDF_BILLING_ADDRESS']]  = $lead->first_name.' '. $lead->last_name;
   // $addressBS[1][$mod_strings['LBL_PDF_BILLING_ADDRESS']]  = $this->bean->billing_account_name;
    $addressBS[1][$mod_strings['LBL_PDF_BILLING_ADDRESS']]  = $lead->primary_address_street;
    if(!empty($lead->primary_address_city) || !empty($lead->primary_address_postalcode)) {
        $addressBS[2][$mod_strings['LBL_PDF_BILLING_ADDRESS']]  = $lead->primary_address_city.", ".$lead->primary_address_state."  ".$lead->primary_address_postalcode;}
```

[image: quote relationship with lead]